# How to get the request string including parameters

Tags: java, servlets

I have an odd exception in our application and I'd like to log when it occurs and include the complete request string including the parameters.

When I try

```
log.warn("Weird request " + request.getRequestURL());
```

I get the request string but not the parameters which were included with ? and &.

example:

```
/testRequest.do?param1=1&param2=2
```

I only see

```
/testRequest.do
```

Can I get this whole string somewhere?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

See [HttpServletRequest#getQueryString()](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString%28%29)

If you want the whole string, you'll have to append the request url and the query string together as there is no method to get the whole thing.

```
System.out.println(request.getRequestURL().append('?').append(request.getQueryString()));
```

Comment: what if there is no parameter, you will show ? at the end.

Comment: @ToKra  Just add some logic to check whether evaluates to null and build out your string based on that : String finalUrl = (request.getQueryString() != null) ?  String.join("", request.getRequestURL(),"?" ,request.getQueryString()) :  request.getRequestURL() ;