# How to access the properties from the Previous Jsp from the Custom Interceptor?

Tags: struts2, struts2-interceptors

Does the **Strings** that i use **in the Action class** which i access as the Properties by means of the  tag **get Stored in Value Stack?**

I have a jsp say JSP1, which has a form with a textInput field that has **name = user**

On submitting the form, an Action class is called. It has access to it by using getters and Setters.

```
But in a Custom Interceptor, how can i access it?
```

I tried to get it from the value stack as

```
ValueStack stack = ai.getStack();
String s = stack.findString("user");
stack.set("user",sa.toUpperCase());
```

But it returns null.

Also i tried to have a String variable with getters and setters in the CustomInterceptor class. It too failed to serve the purpose.

How to get the value to the Interceptor?

Comment: Hard to understand what you're asking, sorry if this is misinterpreted:(In general) You have a form, which you set values. This form is passed to the web application as a request. Struts2 processes the request by setting the values onto the object (among other things). Then a view is rendered. So how to get a variable in the interceptor? Well it depends on where you interceptor is... is it _before_ the parameters are set, or after? If before you need to access the request directly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578998/how-to-get-the-request-string-including-parameters if after...

Comment: then you can access your actions class and directly dig out what you need (and benefit from conversions should you require them). Someone else can more clearly demonstrate both methods.

Comment: As we get the values inputted in the form by getters and setters in the action class, is there a similar method to access the same values in Custom Interceptors?

Comment: The interceptors do the setting from the request... after the parameters interceptor has run (your interceptor follows this one) then you can get the parameters from the Action _Action action = (Action) actionInvocation.getAction();_ You'll want to create an interface and cast the action to it, so you know what it can do... If the action must be _before_ the params interceptors then you'll need to dig in the request, because the values will not be set yet.

Comment: Sorry pal. I don't get it. Can you pls explain it with an example.

Comment: I'll try to make time, but to avoid a future question can you please state what you are trying to do, then the example will probably be a lot more accurate. What is the purpose of your interceptor?

Comment: The value which i enter in a particular textfield should be converted to Upper case for further processing in the action class and later stored in a Db, for which i tried using a custom interceptor.

Comment: What you propose could work, but interceptors are idea for applying "cross-cutting" logic, this seems to be a specific issue. Instead I would A) simply use .toUpperCase() in the setter. B) If this applies to multiple fields use a type converter: http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/type-conversion.html#TypeConversion-BuiltinTypeConversionSupport and using annotations http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/typeconversion-annotation.html don't have time yet to write out something properly yet

Comment: Well thats fine pal. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think you will get your answer on this link : 

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650146/interceptor-cant-access-action-parameters][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650146/interceptor-cant-access-action-parameters

Answer (score 0):

### Invoke defaultStack or params interceptor before custom interceptor:

```
<interceptor-ref name="params"></interceptor-ref>
```

OR

```
<interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
```

Write above line before registering your custom interceptor with the specified action.